# Fill np array with repetitive sequence of integers using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with a sequence of integers like this:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.zeros((1, 100000))
a2 = np.arange(-50, 50+1)
#so a2 looks like this
a2 = [-50, -49, ....., -1, 0, 1, ...., 49, 50]
```

how can i add the sequence of a2, to a1 multiple times in a row?

Comment: Give an example of how your output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `tile` numpy arrays:

```
a1 = np.zeros((1, 100000))
a2 = np.arange(-50, 50+1)
a1 += np.tile(a2, 1000)[:100000]

print(len(a1), repr(a1))
```

It gives:

```
100000 array([-50, -49, -48, ..., -43, -42, -41])
```